# Can I use a 6-digit pin code instead of password in logging in my users in django authentication?

Tags: django, django-authentication

Is there a way where the users can login to my webapp using their username and a 6-digit pin (like the ones we use in our atms) instead of using the password? I am new to django and don't know how or where to look in this.

Thank you!

Comment: you can set that 6 digit pin as the password. that works... you want a seperate one ?? like password and a pin ?

Comment: It would be easier for the user to just use a pin as a password so is it possible to set the pin as password?

Comment: yes. the password field can take in digits(only digits also).

Comment: I see. I'll try to do it and come back here if it worked or not. Thank you!

Comment: I tried creating a user with a password of "123456" and the password field says that it must contain at least 8 characters, must not be too common and that it must be entirely composed of numeric characters. If django restricts it, how should I implement it?

Comment: u created it from the admin panel ?

Comment: In my user registration page.

Comment: No, in my register.html

Comment: try the answer below

Comment: You will have to override default django settings for pasword validation. Use `NumericPasswordValdiator` and set `MinimumLengthValidator` to 6. [More about validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation)

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a class named `FixedDigitPasswordValidator` in a core/normal django app.

```
import re
from django.core.exceptions import (
    ValidationError,
)
class FixedDigitPasswordValidator:
  
    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.match("^[0-9]{6,6}$", password):
            return
        else:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("This password must have only numeric digits of length 6."),
                code='password_entirely_numeric',
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _('Your password must have only numeric digits of length 6.')
```

And at `local_settings.py` file or bottom of `settings.py` file add this line. Python can load class from dotted like path.

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 6,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'dotted_file_path.file_name.FixedDigitPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

Now, each time the user is created that will have exactly 6 digits password.

Answer (score 0):

create a model form of the User :

**views.py :**

```
def signup(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        user_form = User_form(data=request.POST)

        if(user_form.is_valid()):
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    
    else:
        #GET_request
        user_form = User_form()            

    return render(request, "signup_page.html", {'user_form': user_form} )
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User_form(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email" , "password")
```

**signup_page.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}

{% block title %}

Signup

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

        <h3>Please fill in the registration form below,</h3>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <!-- user the enctype attribute because we are uploading images  -->
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <div class="container sign-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    
                    {{ user_form |as_bootstrap  }}
                    <input type="submit" class = “btn btn-default” name="submit" value="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: now you can just enter a 6 digit password numbers only like a pin