# How to implement Token Authentication in Django Rest Framework without using a password?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

How to implement Token Authentication in Django without using a password? Can we override `is_authenticated()` ? Can we use a pin number instead of password?

Answer (score -2):

You can still use a password like usual for Token Auth, just need to add validators to make the password in pin format.

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66972728/11103705) shows you exactly how to do it.

Comment: When an answer to a question already exists, vote to close the question as a duplicate, and don't create yet another answer with nothing else than a link to the existing solution.